# is possible to keep an object across all the activities/fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

i would like to have a "global" object that persist in the application, even when you start other activity or fragment, its kind of annoying to use a bundle to pass the same elements in the app. Maybe with viewmodels? i dont know too much about that , so it would be handy if you give me an example or some guidance in this subject. Thank you in advance:)

Comment: Search for "singletons" in android. This topic has been discussed here extensively.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's pretty simple.

Step 1: Create a java class which extends the Application.

```
import android.app.Application;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    public String yourObj;

    public String getYourObj() {
        return yourObj;
    }

    public void setYourObj(String yourObj) {
        this.yourObj = yourObj;
    }
}
```

Step 2: Define the Application name as your class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.someProject">

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round">
        ...
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here add **android:name=".MyApplication"** inside **<application/>** tag.

Step 3: Now use this where you want inside your application.

```
((MyApplication) getApplication()).setYourObj("...");
((MyApplication) getApplication()).getYourObj();
```

That's it :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended using something similar to an static var, but there is no static var in kotlin, so i used companion objects, it can store a variable perfectly :)

```
class ApplicationData {
   companion object {
      var string:String? =null
   }
 }
```

and its called from any activity or fragment as follows:
ApplicationData.string = "Hi, im a string"

Comment: You can just use `object` instead of a companion object inside a class, so `object ApplicationData` or something. `object` is like a class that there's only one instance of, so it acts as a singleton

Comment: oh ! ill search about that , thanks!